# ASP.NET, EntityFramework - Send minimal data to client

Tags: javascript, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a javascript application with ASP.NET MVC 3, SignalR and Entity Framework in the backend. I have always to prepare the data, because i dont want to send all attributes to the client (performance issue? e.g person has address has country has ... and this for > 1000 person entities). So, now i create always a prepare function before i send the data to the client:

```
public void GetPeople()
{
    PersonRepository personRepository = new PersonRepository(_context);
    var pList = personRepository.GetAll();

    var pClientList = prepare(pList);

    Clients[Context.ConnectionId].loadPeople(pClientList);
}

private object prepare(IEnumerable<Person> pList)
{
    return from p in pList
           select new
           {
                id = p.ID,
                firstName = p.FirstName,
                lastName = p.LastName,
                displayName = p.DisplayName
           };
}
```

and i dont think this is a good practice, because i have to create always for each entity an prepare function and on complex entities it gets weird.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [**AutoMapper**](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) for this.

It also supports [flattening](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Flattening) for complex types, and it's very easy to implement and use.